# Odometer Angular

Tags: angular, odometer

I have performed an odometer with the angular package *tm-ng-odometer*. It works fine for me but I can't get the number movement to start when I get to that section:

```
<tm-ng-odometer [number]="number" [config]="{}"></tm-ng-odometer>
```

```
public number: number = 100;
public config = {
    auto: false,
    selector: 'c-selector'
}
```

Comment: do you have a link to the tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

As stated here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tm-ng-odometer

You must provide and observable that will be triggered to update the odometer like the example:

```
<tm-ng-odometer [number]="number" [config]="{ auto: false }" [observable]="observable"></tm-ng-odometer>
```

And then, you call: `this.observer.next(true)`

Comment: but the rest of the content does not load until it begins to scroll

Comment: and it does not start the odometer when the scroll is on that section